# IndexedSeq-based equivalent of Stream?

Tags: scala

I have a lazily-calculated sequence of objects, where the lazy calculation depends only on the index (not the previous items) and some constant parameters (`p:Bar` below).  I'm currently using a [Stream](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream), however computing the `stream.init` is typically wasteful.

However, I really like that using `Stream[Foo] = ...` gets me out of implementing a cache, and has very light declaration syntax while still providing all the sugar (like `stream(n)` gets element `n`).  Then again, I could just be using the wrong declaration:

```
class FooSrcCache(p:Bar) {
  val src : Stream[FooSrc] = {
    def error() : FooSrc = FooSrc(0,p)
    def loop(i: Int): Stream[FooSrc] = {
      FooSrc(i,p) #:: loop(i + 1)
    }
    error() #:: loop(1)
  }
  def apply(max: Int) = src(max)
}
```

Is there a `Stream`-comparable base Scala class, that is indexed instead of linear?

Comment: Why not use a simple `Map`?

Comment: @Landei it is nice to have an abstraction that hides the mutability from you, which a `Stream` does, a `mutable.Map` obviously not.

Comment: how about an `immutable.Map` then?

Comment: @LuigiPlinge how would you populate an `immutable.Map`? The goal is to have something which evaluates lazily the values you request. (Otherwise a plain old `IndexedSeq` aka `Vector` will do the job)

Comment: @gzm0 you can have your strict collections become lazy by calling the `view` method on them, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

`PagedSeq` should do the job for you:

```
class FooSrcCache(p:Bar) {
    private def fill(buf: Array[FooSrc], start: Int, end: Int) = {
      for (i <- start until end) {
        buf(i) = FooSrc(i,p)
      }
      end - start
    }

    val src = new PagedSeq[FooSrc](fill _)

    def apply(max: Int) = src(max)
}
```

Note that this might calculate `FooSrc` with higher indices than you requested.

Comment: Just back to my desk for a few, but this looks promising.  Will have a go at it later this evening.

Comment: worked with minor modification: I basically ignored the `end` parameter, and simply returned a fixed interval from `start` and returned that interval.

Comment: hrm, except: `PagedSeq` seems to undertake the same behavior as the `Stream`!  which is, it calculates all the pages leading up to the target index.

Comment: @Carl Haha, I see. I guess then you have no choice but to implement it yourself. Maybe have a look at Scalaz, but I'm no expert there.